# Program that takes 2 numbers as an input and finds the factorials of those numbers and every number in between?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, computer-science, factorial

This piece of code is supposed to take 2 numbers and find the factorial of every number between and incuding said numbers. I'm not getting the right output however and cant figure out what im doing wrong.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
long result = 1;
int m = scan.nextInt();
int n = scan.nextInt();
scan.close();

if (n > 0 && m > 0)             //want factorial greater than zero
for(int j = n; j <= m; j++)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
    {
        result = result * i;    //find factorial
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
    if(n <= 0 || m <= 0)        //if value is les than zero
    {
        System.out.println("Not Valid!");
    }
```

Comment: Please post your input numbers and actual output.  Pay close attention to what is considered "m" and "n" - code assumes the 2nd number ("n") is the lesser of the two.  Also, the lack of "open bracket" after the 1st "if" may get you into trouble at some point - though it doesn't appear to be an issue.

Comment: I entered 2 and 5 as my input numbers and get 2, 12, 288, and 34560 as an output but should get 2, 6, 24, and 120

Comment: reset `result` on each iteration of j. so just before the `i` loop: `result = 1`;

Comment: Oh wow, it's as simple as that, it does make sense that you'd rest the result. I knew i wasn't far off thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like should work:

```java
public class RangeFactorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = scan.nextInt();
        int min = scan.nextInt();

        if (max < 0 || min < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Params");
        }

        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            System.out.println("Factorial for " + i + " is: " + factorial(i));
        }

        scan.close();
    }

    private static int factorial(int i) {
        if (i <= 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return i * factorial(i-1);
    }
}
```

Note that the code assumes that max/min fall in place, I've omitted the logic to decide the max/min integer from the given inputs. You'll need to add this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset 'result' to 1.

Also, there is no need to have another if statement if it is only checking for the negation of the first one, just use an else.

I also fixed the code style guidelines to follow the standard Java ones as:

1. The curly bracket style you used is the one usually used in C/C++.
2. Even if if-statements or loops contain only one line after them, it is good etiquette to use curly brackets anyway, in Java.

Take a look at the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) if you want to know more.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    long result = 1;
    int m = scan.nextInt();
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();

    if (n > 0 && m > 0){
        for(int j = n; j <= m; j++){
            result = 1; //You forgot to reset 'result'
            for(int i = 1; i <= j; i++){
                result *= i;   
            }
        System.out.println(result);
    } else { // No need for another if statement
        System.out.println("Not Valid!");
    }
```